# Export files from sharepoint online to FTP using flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

I have a requirement where a Microsoft Flow should export the files from SharePoint online Document library to a FTP server

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I have a requirement where when we drop files in sharepoint library like images (all formats) word documents pdfs then a flow should trigger and those dropped files should be copied to a FTP server location (linux based servers)

Comment: Again, what's the question?

Comment: The same question i asked twice sir @Colbs

Answer (score 0):

In Flow, the is a "Copy File to FTP" action, so you would do something like: When new file is created in XYZ library, copy to FTP